# How to continue table on the next page?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I'm using a table with a lot of rows, and it's impossible to fit in only one page. I would like to continue the table on the next page, but the table disappears.

My code is:

```
\subsubsection{UC 02 - Gerenciar Memorial}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Caso de Uso 02 - Gerenciar Memorial}
\label{uc02}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\textbf{CASO DE USO} & \textbf{UC02 - Gerenciar Memorial} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
\textbf{CASO DE USO} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}UC02 – Gerenciar Memorial \\(Caso de Uso Pacote: \\Alterar Memorial)\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
\textbf{Ator} & Usuário Registrado \\ \hline
\textbf{Descrição} & Este caso de uso descreve os passos percorridos pelo responsável por um memorial para alterar dados  ele contidos. \\ \hline
\textbf{Pré-Condições} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}1. Estar autenticado no sistema.\\   2. Ser responsável pelo memorial a ser \\alterado.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\textbf{Pós-Condições} & 1. Memorial alterado com sucesso. \\ \hline
\textbf{Requisitos} & RF03 (Gerenciar Memorial). \\ \hline
\textbf{Regras de Negócio} & RN01 (Níveis de Permissão). \\ \hline
\textbf{Estrutura de Dados} & As tabelas “Memorial”, “MidiaDigital” e “Evento”. \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Fluxo Principal}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Ator}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Sistema}} \\ \hline
1. Em sua página de perfil, o usuário escolhe a opção de edição de memorial referente ao  memorial desejado na listagem de memoriais administrados pelo usuário. &  \\ \hline
 & 2. O sistema abre o formulário de alteração com todos os dados do memorial cadastrados pelo usuário exibidos na tela. \\ \hline
3. O usuário realiza as alterações desejadas e confirma as alterações. &  \\ \hline
 & 4. O sistema valida todas as alterações e salva as alterações no banco de dados. \\ \hline
 & 5. O sistema redireciona o usuário para a visualização do memorial editado. \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Fluxo alternativo}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Ator}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Sistema}} \\ \hline
1. Em sua página de perfil, o usuário escolhe a opção de edição de memorial referente ao memorial desejado na listagem de memoriais administrados pelo usuário. &  \\ \hline
 & 2. O sistema abre o formulário de alteração com todos os dados do memorial cadastrados pelo usuário exibidos na tela. \\ \hline
3. O usuário realiza as alterações desejadas, porém cancela a operação. &  \\ \hline
 & 4. O sistema redireciona o usuário para a sua página de perfil. \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Fluxo de Exceção} \\ \hline
1. Em sua página de perfil, o usuário escolhe a opção de edição de memorial referente ao memorial desejado na listagem de memoriais administrados pelo usuário. &  \\ \hline
 & 2. O sistema abre o formulário de alteração com todos os dados do memorial cadastrados pelo usuário exibidos na tela. \\ \hline
3. O usuário realiza as alterações desejadas e confirma as alterações. &  \\ \hline
 & 4. O sistema valida todas as alterações e encontra erros. \\ \hline
 & 5. O sistema retorna para o formulário de alteração, indicando quais erros de entrada de dados foram cometidos pelo usuário. \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Fluxo de Exceção}} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Ator}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Sistema}} \\ \hline
1. Em sua página de perfil, o usuário escolhe a opção de edição de memorial referente ao memorial desejado na listagem de memoriais administrados pelo usuário. &  \\ \hline
 & 2. O sistema abre o formulário de alteração com todos os dados do memorial cadastrados pelo usuário exibidos na tela. \\ \hline
3. O usuário realiza as alterações desejadas e confirma as alterações. &  \\ \hline
 & 4. O sistema valida todas as alterações e encontra erros. \\ \hline
 & 5. O sistema retorna para o formulário de alteração, indicando quais erros de entrada de dados foram cometidos pelo usuário. \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

The result:

[image: result of code]

Comment: There is the `longtable` package (amongst others), that 'wrap' the table ...

Comment: I've tried to use the longtable, but the table is not fit in the page ...

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida: Then you need to provide an example of what you tried in that regard. As it stands, your question is a duplicate. Note that `longtable` cannot break the tabular content mid-cell. That is, paragraph content spanning multiple lines will be kept on either page rather than be broken in the middle. If you want this kind of behaviour, you can't use a (long)table.

Comment: I've used the \begin{longtable}{| p{.20\textwidth} | p{.80\textwidth} |} and now its working! thanks

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida: Note that `.2\textwidth` + `.8\textwidth` + `4\tabcolsep` + `3\arrayrulewidth` > `\textwidth`, so you'll get an overfull `\hbox` warning.

Comment: You can use `tabularx`  the same way as `longtable`with the `ltablex` package + the directive `\keepXColumns`.